# What needs to be mounted by the kubernetes device plugin in order to use GPU inside containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I have built a **GPU device plugin for kubernetes**. GPU devices are getting allocated by the plugin, but the GPU drivers are not getting detected inside the container. As much I know, I need to mount several directories in order for the container to detect Nvidia drivers.

I am using the **nvidia/cuda:12.0.0-devel-ubuntu22.04** docker image due to which cuda is being detected, but for nvidia drivers I am not sure what all directories needs to be mounted by the device plugin. I have tried mounting /usr/local/nvidia, but it gives me CreateContainerError. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You should install nvidia-container-toolkit in all nodes.

```
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/$distribution/libnvidia-container.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libnvidia-container.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
```

Next step
edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
    "default-runtime": "nvidia",
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}
```

Install plugin

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/1.0.0-beta4/nvidia-device-plugin.yml
```

You can read more [https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin](https://k8s-device-plugin)

Comment: I have my own custom device plugin, I dont want to use the nvidia plugin. Device plugin mounts certain directories when it allots devices to the containers in order to make the GPU visible inside the container. I am stuck in trying to find what exactly are the things I need to mount.